# Regex 1 uppercase, check if following characters are lowercase

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

As the title says, I wanna check if the 1st letter of a string is uppercase and then I wanna check if any of the following letters in the string is 1 or more uppercase.

I've made it this far, but it's too hard.

`$regex = ('/^.*[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,}.*$/');`

Comment: Then you should read more clearly. Anyway: As my prob says: `I wanna check if the 1st letter of a string is uppercase and then I wanna check if any of the following letters in the string is 1 or more uppercase.`. I want that <<.

Comment: @user3613655 be nice. He is trying to help you :)

Comment: @user3613655, **lowercase** is in the title, but not in the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
^(?=.*?.[A-Z])[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+$
```

`(?=.*?.[A-Z])` Asserts that there must be an uppercase letter after a character.

Answer (score 2):

Use following regular expression:

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/
```

with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
echo(preg_match('/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/', 'Hello')); // 1
echo(preg_match('/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/', 'hello')); // 0
echo(preg_match('/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/', 'HEllo')); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/
```

mathces the first character to uppercase followed by one or more lower case